# What can be the rating and specifications of dc motor used for making a quadcopter?

Tags: quadcopter

I want to make a quadcopter for my final year project and I am willing to use DC motors as the four rotors of the quadcopter. Can any one guide me about the ratings for proper motor selection for my job.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use brushless (as opposed to brushed) motors for a quadcopter:

see [Why do quadcopters use brushless motors](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/why-do-quadcopters-use-brushless-motors)

The motor goes hand in hand with the propellers, so you have to make sure they are compatible for your application, as you'll need to generate enough thrust to get it to fly (so it will depend on the weight):

see [How to choose the right propeller/motor combination for a quadcopter?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/25/how-to-choose-the-right-propeller-motor-combination-for-a-quadcopter)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to build a really cheap but great flying quadcopter, check out coreless micro motors: http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2009496

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* benedikt, but I'm afraid that one line/link only answers really aren't very useful on Stack Exchange. Links [rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) and forum threads get so large they become impossible to navigate them. Please consider editing your answer to highlight a specific post within the thread and quote some of the most relevant text to provide some context. Even better would be to use the information in that thread to create an answer which summarises the most relevant parts of the thread. Thanks,